# Unable to install and run MySQL properly when using downloaded zip

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1045

I have been trying to install MySQL from a direct zip and I've followed each step in [this](http://umaranis.com/2016/11/04/run-mysql-without-installation/#comment-27462) doc.

The FLUSH PRIVILEGES throws the error :
access denied you need (at least one of) the reload privilege(s) for this operation

I then tried : GRANT reload on *.* to 'root'@'localhost'.  This gives the error :
Access denied for user ''@localhost;
Am not able to execute any query. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: This scheme for installing MySQL without using the installer is, simply put, a grim hack. Can you rely on it to work? No. Lots of things could be wrong: file system access comes to mind.

Comment: Well , using the installer too didn't work. I was never able to connect to the server. MySQL wouldn't accept any configured root password without a special character in it. This is the reason, I switched to the zip folder approach